# What are all these unicorn processes? or are they threads?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn

I'm running an Ruby on Rails app using Unicorn. We configured our server to run three workers, but when I look at it with htop, I see what looks like the three workers and then, each of them have several sub-process, or are they threads? What's going on? What are they?

[image]

Comment: in htop: F2, Display options, disable "Hide userland threads" and see if anything changes

Comment: @keymone yes, that was it, thank you. Feel free to create the answer for the reputation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those processes are most probably threads. To figure out which are threads and which are child processes go to htop settings: `F2 -> Display options` and disable `Hide userland threads` or toggle `Display threads in a different color`.

Comment: Can u help me @keymone  in understanding why these threads have different process ids.?

Comment: @jily stackoverflow.com/a/9306150/166029 - this answers it better than i could